# How to fix ‘TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable’ error in Python

Tags: python

when I run my code I get:
       
 `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'`

at the line: 

`centroids[key] = [m / len(assignments[key]) for m in clust_sum]`

This is my python code:

```
def k_means_clust(data,num_clust,num_iter,w=5):
    centroids=random.sample(data,num_clust)
    counter=0
    for n in range(num_iter):
        counter+=1
        print counter
        assignments={}
        #assign data points to clusters
        for ind,i in enumerate(data):
            min_dist=float('inf')
            closest_clust=None
            for c_ind,j in enumerate(centroids):
                if LB_Keogh(i,j,5)<min_dist:
                    cur_dist=DTWDistance(i,j,w)
                    if cur_dist<min_dist:
                        min_dist=cur_dist
                        closest_clust=c_ind
            if closest_clust in assignments:
                assignments[closest_clust].append(ind)
            else:
                assignments[closest_clust]=[]

        #recalculate centroids of clusters
        for key in assignments:
            clust_sum=0
            for k in assignments[key]:
                clust_sum=clust_sum+data[k]
            centroids[key]=[m/len(assignments[key]) for m in clust_sum] #<-HERE ERROR 

    return centroids
```

I can't understand the reason why I got this error. 

The variable `clust_sum` is a `numpy.ndarray`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "The variable clust_sum is a numpy.ndarray " => no, it isn't - cf `clust_sum=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redefined clust_sum just before your loop

```
clust_sum=0
```

So clust_sum is now an int, and you cannot iterate on it

```
centroids[key]=[m/len(assignments[key]) for m in clust_sum]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put "clust_sum=0" out of the iteration:

```
    clust_sum=0
    #recalculate centroids of clusters
    for key in assignments:
        for k in assignments[key]:
            clust_sum=clust_sum+data[k]
        centroids[key]=[m/len(assignments[key]) for m in clust_sum]

return centroids
```